# Pass saved Workout from Watch to iPhone

Tags: swift, watchkit, healthkit

On Watch, I'm able to pass a saved workout from the `WorkoutInterfaceController` to the `SummaryInterfaceController`. But I was wondering how to **pass the saved workout from the Watch to the iPhone** (so I can display it in a Summary View Controller too).

Do you know?  Or is there a better way I'm supposed to do this?

*Here's what I use to pass the saved workout from `WorkoutInterfaceController` to the `SummaryInterfaceController`:*

```
private func saveWorkout() {
    // Create and save a workout sample
    let configuration = workoutSession!.workoutConfiguration
    let isIndoor = (configuration.locationType == .indoor) as NSNumber
    print("locationType: \(configuration)")

    let workout = HKWorkout(activityType: configuration.activityType,
                            start: workoutStartDate!,
                            end: workoutEndDate!,
                            workoutEvents: workoutEvents,
                            totalEnergyBurned: totalEnergyBurned,
                            totalDistance: totalDistance,
                            metadata: [HKMetadataKeyIndoorWorkout:isIndoor]);

    healthStore.save(workout) { success, _ in
        if success {
            self.addSamples(toWorkout: workout)
        }
    }

    WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers(withNames: ["SummaryInterfaceController"], contexts: [workout])
}

private func addSamples(toWorkout workout: HKWorkout) {
    // Create energy and distance samples
    let totalEnergyBurnedSample = HKQuantitySample(type: HKQuantityType.activeEnergyBurned(),
                                                   quantity: totalEnergyBurned,
                                                   start: workoutStartDate!,
                                                   end: workoutEndDate!)

    // Add samples to workout
    healthStore.add([totalEnergyBurnedSample], to: workout) { (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
        if success {
            // Samples have been added
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if any questions or information needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a part of my research and development,I discovered how the pairing of the iPhone and the Apple Watch has the potential to be useful.
In this case, tapping on a button on the Watch app will send text on the iPhone.

To make a simple demo of this functionality, place a button on the WatchKit interface and a label on the iOS app’s storyboard.

Now, hook up the button to the WatchKit Interface Controller as an IBAction in order to respond to button tap events. Also hook up the Label to the UI View Controller as an IBOutlet.

In the Interface Controller, we make up a string variable to send to the label and in the button’s IBAction method, make a dictionary that includes the string variable you made. This dictionary is what is passed to the iPhone app.

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
    Var str: String = "Hello Phone"
    @IBAction func button() {
        let dict: Dictionary = ["message": str]
    }
```

Use the following method to send the dictionary to the iPhone.

```
WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(dict, reply: {(reply, error) -> void in
     print("Reply receive from iPhone app")
})
```

In the AppDelegate of the iOS app, add the following application method. This is what will handle the previous methods communication from the Watch. Also we can use a notification to notify a view controller that data has been received and to pass it along.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleWatchkitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, reply:(([NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("WatchKitReq", object: userInfo)
}
```

Finally in the view controller, make a listener for the notification that will update the label’s text to the string that was sent with the data.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector("handleWatchKitNotification:"), name: "WatchKitReq", object: nil)
}
func handleWatchKitNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.object as? [String : String] {
        label.text = userInfo["message"]
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you to understand. For more concerns you can look on this,

[Delegate Method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623041-application?language=objc)

Answer (score 1):

To do this you have to create an App Group which is essentially a space which both apps can use. It was brought in with the exetension framework in iOS8 so apps can communicate with their Today widgets, or custom keyboards, and amongst other applications.

**ADD CAPABILITIES**

The first thing we have to do is add the app group capability to both our iPhone and Watch Watch Extension targets.

To do this open up the project settings (blue icon at the top of the list of files) and select the iPhone target. You will need to select the “capabilities” tab at the top of the page and scroll down to turn on app groups.

This requires a connected developer profile, and will take a while to enable. You’ll need to do the same steps to switch on app groups for the watch kit extension also.

Next you need to ensure that the app group string is an identifier string you want and that makes sense for your app, it must start with the word group or it complains. You can also add multiple groups if you wish. Whatever you pick they must be enabled with a blue tick (again this might take a while) and are exactly the same for both the iPhone and Watch extension targets!

[image: Capabilities Image]

To use App Groups, it’s not that different or difficult to use than NSUserDefaults:

```
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.example.My-App")
userDefaults.setObject(true, forKey: "isDarkModeEnabled")
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

The only differences here are how NSUserDefaults is instantiated and calling synchronize at the end. You feed it the container ID to the constructor parameter called “suiteName”, then call “synchronize()”, and your data flies to the cloud for other apps and devices to consume.

**Taking It to the Next Level**

You can take this one step further by creating a class for your app and abstract the underlying storage for your properties. Here’s an example:

```
public class ConfigurationModel: NSObject {

public static let storageKey = "group.com.example.My-App"
public let userStorage = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: storageKey)

public var isDarkModeEnabled: Bool {
 get {
    // Get setting from storage or default
    if userStorage?.objectForKey("isDarkModeEnabled") == nil {
       userStorage?.setObject(false, forKey: "isDarkModeEnabled")
       userStorage?.synchronize()
    }

     return userStorage?.objectForKey("isDarkModeEnabled")
 }

 set {
    // Set new value in storage
    userStorage?.setObject(newValue, forKey: "isDarkModeEnabled")
    userStorage?.synchronize()
 }
}
```

At the top of the class, I am declaring my group container ID and creating the NSUserDefault object out of it. Then my properties for the class have getters and setters to store the data to the App Group. If the key doesn’t exist, it creates it with a default value and synchronizes it. Using the class from this point forward is simple:

```
var configModel = ConfigurationModel()
configModel.isDarkModeEnabled = true
```

This property is stored in the cloud! Everything is abstracted away for you. You don’t have to be bothered about storing and synchronizing it into the App Group. It’s all done automatically for you in the getters and setters!

Hope, this will help you to understand how you can share data between the iPhone and Apple Watch app.

Comment: Does watchOS 3 support App Groups though?  I'm pretty sure all the way back to watchOS 2 doesn't support UserDefaults, and for some reason I'm thinking that was the same for App Groups.  But I could totally be wrong, I'm trying to find documentation on it!

Comment: Yes WatchOS 3 supports App Groups, you can check it on:

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/SharingData.html

Comment: you can get briefly info about all methods here,

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/SharingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH29-SW1

Comment: you can use below method to send data... sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:
sendMessageData:replyHandler:errorHandler:

Comment: Have you tried this in watchOS3? Getting the data on the iPhone side that was saved on the Watch side doesn't work for me.